# How can I change host Name for Apache tomcat server?

Tags: apache, tomcat, hosts

I installed `Apache Tomcat 6.0`,I tested with simple Application it's working fine.but every time I calling my app with `localhost:8080` in the browser.

I want to change host name(localhost) to something like `subbu`.for this I tried in the following way.

I open command prompt and entered `drivers` and after selected `etc` folder, open `host` file .in this file I changed subbu instead of `localhost`.After did this I restarted my system and started `apache server` and entered in my browser like `subbu:8080`.it's not working.

I hope,you understand what I faced problem.

How can I resolve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `/etc/hosts` change the line

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

to be

```
127.0.0.1       localhost subbu
```

Comment: after changing the host name,will I restart anything out of system,apache tomcat and browser.
already I restarted Apache and browser and entered `localhost subbu:8080` in browser but it's not working.

Comment: @subbu: You might like to try entering just `subbu:8080`. Also I recommend reading `man hosts`.

Comment: sorry,I reopen `Apache Tomcat` and entered `subbu:8080` in the browser but still it's not working.

Comment: @subbu: What do you get as result for a `ping subbu` in the console? And what do you get for `ping localhost`?

Comment: I got `Oops! Google Chrome could not find subbu:8080` like this.